# Difference between retain

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsstring, memory-management, retain

what's the difference between these retains?:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *A_StringToRetain;
```

and

```
NSString *B_StringToRetain;
B_StringToRetain = [[MyClass GetStringValue] retain];
```

Because using property, string won't retain and using second ways, all ok, but i need to check and release to avoid leaks.

---

**Example**:
I declared in `.h`

```
NSString *A_StringToRetain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *A_StringToRetain;
```

in `.m` i use

```
A_StringToRetain = @"MyValue";
```

but when i exit from method, I lost `A_StringToRetain`. It's a zombie.

If i not use a property and declare a string in this way

```
NSString *B_StringToRetain;
B_StringToRetain = [[MyClass GetStringValue] retain];
```

the string is in memory.

---

Anyone tell me why please?
It's not the same way to alloc/retain?
What's differences?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the variable directly and NOT going through the property (which applies a retain)... you either need...

```
self.A_StringToRetain = someString;
```

or

```
[self setA_StringToRetain:someString];
```

The key here is the `self.` which means you go via the property and not directly to the ivar itself.

Comment: Great! I'm a stupid! :) Now it's clear and obviously works! thanks.